# What is the correct way of handling firebase user creation flow in react-redux application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I've been writing my React/Rediux/Firebase app for some time (started ~1year ago, but I had some few months breaks during this time - so I can review my own code from a time perspective).
Now I'm checking the code again and I have gut feeling that it's not the state of the art.

I am using Firebase also for managing account, in this case for creating a new one

I put all the chain of actions related to creation of user and error handling in one function block in Actions/index.js.

```
export const signUpUser = (data) => dispatch => {
  Firebase.auth().createUserAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
    .then(response => {
      const userId = Firebase.auth().currentUser()
      getUserInfoRef(userId).set({
        uid: userId,
        isAdmin: false
      })
    })
    .then(response => {
      Firebase.auth().currentUser().updateProfile({
        displayName: `${data.name} ${data.surname}`
      })
    })
    .then(() => {
      dispatch(sendEmailVerification())
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error during signUpUser', error)
      dispatch(authError(error))
    })
}
```

but is this a good approach? 
Isn't dispatching actions from its body some kind of anti pattern? 
Maybe it should be split somehow (how?) ?

It's working, but I'm not delighted by how it looks :)
Please, advise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. As long as you are using promise with the `then`, `catch` blocks it has to dispatched within.
But if you still want it to look better i will suggest you use `async/await` like this:

```
export const signUpUser = (data) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    await Firebase.auth().createUserAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)

    const userId = await Firebase.auth().currentUser()

    getUserInfoRef(userId).set({
      uid: userId,
      isAdmin: false
    }) // am not sure if this func is async or not

    await Firebase.auth().currentUser().updateProfile({
      displayName: `${data.name} ${data.surname}`
    })

    dispatch(sendEmailVerification())
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('Error during signUpUser', error)
    dispatch(authError(error))
  }
}
```

PS: It's nice to see SO asking people to be "nice" here. I think it's very much needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response @femi-oni
What I am concerned about it is amount of stuff done by this function and all the chaining.
And actions are supposed to be rather simple - at least this is my understanding.

Comment: Ah! Yes! actions should do as little as possible. In that case i will suggest break it in two : `createUser` and `updateUser` (which you need as it own function anyways). so if you `dispatch(updateUser)` from within `createUser` `dispatch` is automatically made available in `updateUser`